# Teamcity GitHub Private Key FileNotFoundException (No such file or directory)

Tags: git, teamcity, bitbucket

I been trying for about three hours to create a VCS Root pointing to a Github repository using "Private Key" as the the Authentication method.

[image]
[image]

But when I hit the "Test Connection" button I get this error back:

```
Test connection failed in Apms :: GateControl :: Nightly. List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\key\private (No such file or directory)
```

The private key definitely exists, and I've even cloned the repository using this same key using SmartGit.

If anyone has successfully set this up please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since version 8.1 you can upload SSH private key to a project in TeamCity, and then select this key in VCS root settings. This approach is simpler and does not require you to place the same key on both agent and server. See also: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/SSH+Keys+Management